# Why lldb dump `___lldb_unnamed_function1$$64.out` message, when it steps over assembly `loop` instruction

Tags: assembly, lldb

After I studied assembly loop instruction. I want to test whether or not it works in OS X.

```
.data
output:
    .asciz "The value is: %d\n"
.text
.globl _main
_main:
    movq    $0xffffffff, %rcx
    movq    $0, %rax
loop1:
    addq    %rcx, %rax
    loop    loop1
done:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    leaq    output(%rip), %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    call    _printf
    addq    $8, %rsp

    subq    $8, %rsp
    movq    $0, %rdi
    call    _exit
```

This code snippet exactly works correctly. But when I used lldb to test it step by step, some strange message was dumped.The lldb printed

```
a.out`___lldb_unnamed_function1$$a.out:
-> 0x1fa4:  addq   %rcx, %rax
    0x1fa7:  loop   0x1fa4                    ; ___lldb_unnamed_function1$$a.out

a.out`done at main_64.s:16:
   0x1fa9:  subq   $0x8, %rsp
   0x1fad:  leaq   0x6c(%rip), %rdi          ; output
```

What's wrong with it? Doesn't it support loop instruction?

In addition, I used `br s -a 0x1fa4 -c '$rcx==0x2'` to set a breakpoint at address 0x1fa4 when `%rcx==0x2`, but after the program was continued again the lldb was out of control. The prompt was printed immediately and cpu went high. I try to entered `p/x $rcx` but got nothing. Can anyone tell me what happened? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`___lldb_unnamed_function1` seems to be sign of missing symbol information. It is not an error message. To get rid of it, try to compile your assembly source with debugging options on.

The breakpoint you set had condition to stop execution only when `RCX` became equal to `0x2`. Your CPU went high because you did a lot of decrementation, and after `RCX` became zero, processor continued on the next instruction.